# innerHTML does not show unicode text correctly

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, innerhtml

What is wrong with this code:

```
        document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = "Jürgen";
```

How can I make it that this text with à ü ë and so on is displayed correctly?

In the head I have set:

```
       meta charset="UTF-8"

       meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

But this does not seem to work.

I also tried replacing ü with \uü. Also didnt work.

Comment: Just tested it and it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/5cgebsL8/

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a snippet here and what do you exacly mean by displayed incorrectly?

Comment: I see your jsfiddle and it works there. That is very strange.

Comment: @demkovych In JSFiddle your code works. But if I make a doc and open it in real life (firefox, chrome) it doesn't. So I guess this must be a wrong interpretation in JSFiddle.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the JSFiddle, it is working exactly as expected and like it should. You mention in a comment on an answer below that `Jürgen` is coming from a database, not a string constant as shown in your question. That fact is _**CRITICAL**_ to answering the question. This is _most likely_ a problem with keeping the interpretation of the char encoding consistent through the chain of connections (I once had a similar issue because the database _**driver**_ was configured incorrectly, even though the DB, schema, tables, and columns were all correct). Please edit your question.

Comment: To check if it was a database problem I hardcoded the text just as I asked in the question above with the same wrong result. However, I found out something else: I put your two lines of jsfiddle code inside a document and ran it from my server. Unicode characters do not display right. They are replaced by a questionmark. HOWEVER: The name of the document on my server had the .txt extension. Once I changed it to .html it displayed correctly. So apparently the extension of the file has an impact on how it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes need to use special HTML codes to display those letters. Just paste these provided codes (without quotation marks) wherever you need those letters / symbols inside your HTML, like this:

```html
<p>My letter a fancy is like this &aacute;</p>
```

1. For à use `"&aacute"`
2. For ü use  `"&uuml";`
3. For ë use `"&euml"`;

Comment: You got them wrong, it's `&agrave;` instead of `&aacute`, and `&uuml;` instead of `&uacute`

Comment: Maybe I did, here is the page with every code included. https://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html

Comment: The innerHTML is actually filled from a database. Does this mean I really need to replace all these characters in the complete database with codes? There must be a better solution than this one. These are just a few of the letters. But there are many more.

Comment: @RichardLleram you should precise in the question what your currently get. Is your database field properly set to UTF-8? Are the characters properly displayed when you test with `"Jürgen"` as a fixed test value?

Comment: My question is exactly as I said. To test if it was the database I replaced it with this fixed string. With the same wrong result. These characters are replaced by a questionmark.

Comment: It should be possible to use non-ASCII characters without resorting to using HTML entities like `&aacute;`

Comment: @RichardLleram as Kaddath says, you should be precise. "this does not seem to work" is not precise. What _**exactly**_ do you get as the output? You omit from your question that there is database storage involved, and which database, and how you have char encodings set for it. You do **not** "need" to use the character entity references, you _do_ need to get your encoding settings correct as the text gets stored in the database, retrieved, and displayed in the page.

Comment: @RichardLleram - and - you do _**not**_ have to replace all those characters in the database with character entity references ("codes") — Do **Not** Do That! You definitely want the database to store the actual data, not some interpretation of the data that convenient for HTML display.

Answer (score 0):

For the Umlaut you will need to replace the u with the below html code which should show the correct output

```
&uuml;
```

Answer (score 0):

To properly declare your charset, note that it must be:

> Within the `<head>` element,

> Before any elements that contain text, such as the `<title>` element,

> AND Within the first 512 bytes of your document, including DOCTYPE and whitespace

(source: [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/archive/p/doctype-mirror/wikis/MetaCharsetAttribute.wiki))

In short, it should be the first thing in your page `<head>`.

Also, I can't find the reference anymore, but it seems that it's not syntactically correct to use both `<meta charset="utf-8">` and `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`. At least, it is quite useless, they mean the same thing. The second one is deprecated and should be used only for very old browsers compatibility.

And of course, your HTML file should be saved in UTF-8 too.

I hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, try using utf8_encode(text) to see if works!

example:

```
var html = `
    <p class="project-title"><?php print utf8_encode($title); ?></p>
    <p class="project-desc"><?php print utf8_encode($description); ?></p>`

document.body.innerHTML += html;
```

This worked for me :)